# Xcode adds ".app" to target names ending with ".cc"

Tags: ios, xcode

Can anyone fix or confirm this behaviour in Xcode (6.3.2):

Ending the name of an iOS project target with ".cc" like "something.cc" automatically adds ".app" to end of the name at runtime…?!

something.cc -> something.cc.app

Comment: Hasn't 6.3.2 been withdrawn?  The latest I saw yesterday was 6.3.1.

Comment: The AppStore says current version is 6.3.2. – Maybe someone already using Xcode 7 can test this issue, I think it is still not fixed…

Answer (score 0):

This is now confirmed by others and obviously a bug: http://openradar.appspot.com/21319069

Thanks to Paul Hemetsbeger there is a workaround: Using the unicode letter "․" fixes the problem. Only the "delete this app alert view" gets a little bit messed up…